# Sample a dataframe with replacement column-wise in R

Tags: r, resampling

I have a dataframe with 40 columns and seven observations. I would like to resample the dataset 1000 times but columnwise. No replacement of data outside of the columns.

When I use the function sample with replacement = TRUE. It replaces the column. But, what I would like to do is to only resample the data within the column, and leave every column as they are. I also tried using the argument groups in sample function but failed.

Any help is appreciated.

```
# example data 
          c1 c2 c3   c4     c5       c40
r1       1.0  2  4  7.0    14.0      3.5
r2       2.0  4  6  8.0    20.0      5.0
r3       3.0  6 10 15.0     3.0      6.0
r4       1.5  3  5  7.5     1.5      3.0
r5       1.5  3  5  7.5     1.5      3.0
r7       1.5  3  5  7.5     1.5      3.0

trial = sample(group1_base, replace = TRUE)

View(trial)

          c1 c2 c1   c4     c5       c4
r1       1.0  2  4  7.0    14.0      3.5
r2       2.0  4  6  8.0    20.0      5.0
r3       3.0  6 10 15.0     3.0      6.0
r4       1.5  3  5  7.5     1.5      3.0
r5       1.5  3  5  7.5     1.5      3.0
r7       1.5  3  5  7.5     1.5      3.0
```

Comment: regarding resample 1000 times, do you expect 1000 datasets

Comment: yes, with the small dataset I have I want to resample it 1000 times in order to calculate the output for each observation with the model I have. I am not sure if it makes sense with the sample size that I have.

Comment: If you need to do the sampling on each column 'n' times, use `replicate` as in Georgery's post.  `n <- 10;lapply(group1_base, function(vec) replicate(n,   sample(vec, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE))`

Comment: what would be the difference between looping over lapply function and the replicate here?

Comment: If you are askiing about the previous code, then `lapply` is looping over each column and `replicate` does the replication of the sampling done on each column to 'n' times

Answer (score 1):

We can loop over the columns with `lapply` and do the `sample`

```
group1_base[] <- lapply(group1_base, sample, replace = TRUE)
```